# Integration microsoft teams apis in ruby language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, microsoft-teams

I read in documentation of microsoft teams this :

```
To deploy apps that are integrated with the Education APIs in Microsoft Graph, school IT admins must first grant consent to the permissions requested by the app. This consent has to be granted only once, unless the permissions change. After the admin consents, the app is provisioned for all users in the tenant.
```

If i have `tenant` and `clientID` what must be the code in ruby to implement this ?
And if i want to get class what code i should be do?

```
Example please for begin in this !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to create an App for Teams, you need to register an entry for it in the Azure portal. How you do this, depends on the kind of app and how you intend to use it, but for a Tab in Teams, for example, you do this in the Azure App Registrations screen [here](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade). There are more steps thereafter depending on what you're trying to do (see here for instance on creating an app with SSO capabilities to integrate with Graph, which sounds like what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?source=docs#steps)

Once that's done, an administrator needs to grant consent to your application, on behalf of all the users in the organisation to make use of it. It would involve the admin visiting a url like:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}` and going through the consent process. "Client Id" is the application id for the app you registered earlier.